# GitHub Pages: How do I edit this page in markdown format, just as I created it?

Tags: github, markdown, github-pages

I'm not too comfortable with touching the generated HTML that the site gives, I was wondering whether there is any way to change the contents of my page in markdown formatting, the same way that I did upon creating the page?

Any input as to go about doing this would be awesome.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

By default, [GitHub Pages](http://pages.github.com/) helps you generate html pages only.

But if you setup your site to use [jekyll](https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll), then you can store files in markdown. For example, in the `_posts` section of [this repo '`cboettig/labnotebook`'](https://github.com/cboettig/labnotebook/tree/master/_posts) which is generated to [`carlboettiger.info`](http://carlboettiger.info/).

See Help page "[Using Jekyll with Pages](https://help.github.com/articles/using-jekyll-with-pages)"

More specifically (as highlighted in [esfandia](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1641163/esfandia)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40009754/6309)), see <del>"[The Automatic Page Generator](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-pages-with-the-automatic-generator/#the-automatic-page-generator)"</del>, which allows for markdown editing.

[image: https://help.github.com/assets/images/help/pages/pages-automatic-page-generator.png]

As [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15044353/github-pages-how-do-i-edit-this-page-in-markdown-format-just-as-i-created-it/15047448#comment76673772_15047448) by [dregad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1045774/c), there is a [**new theme chooser** in Dec. 2016](https://github.com/blog/2295-new-theme-chooser-for-github-pages):

[image: https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/849592/21229008/24006df6-c2ae-11e6-94a4-ca4eb085f5f4.png]

See [this article](http://antrikshy.com/blog/noob-guide-to-hosting-cheap-website-blog-jekyll-github-pages-2) by **[Antriksh Yadav](https://twitter.com/Antrikshy)**:

[image: http://antrikshy.com/assets/github-page-generator-edit.png]

---

Update August 2016: **[Simpler GitHub Pages publishing](https://github.com/blog/2228-simpler-github-pages-publishing)** now allows to keep your page files in a subfolder of the *same* branch (no more `gh-pages` needed):

[image: Now you can select a source in your repository settings and GitHub Pages will look for your content there.]

So you don't need multiple branch anymore.

Comment: In the case of the a project page, I don't see the markdown source anywhere.

Comment: @NathanLong did you write any file in the `gh-pages` branch?

Comment: `index.html` was created in the `gh-pages` branch, but I was expecting something like `index.markdown`.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all.  Where's the markdown?

Comment: @djechlin you are right. I have rewritten the answer to emphasize where markdown pages can be in a "GitHub Page" repo.

Comment: still a terrible answer.  is it possible to obtain the default markdown (that you can edit directly in github) or not?

Comment: @si28719e in the `_posts` folder of your repo. Not sure what you mean by "default markdown" though.

Comment: i mean, if you do not use jekyll, the markdown is not accessible, except via the github web ui. there is no _posts directory in this case.

Comment: @si28719e correct, if you don't use Jekyll, all you get back is generated html pages for you to modify.

Comment: got it. thanks for the update in this regard. i tried to change my vote but i guess it is locked. :|

Comment: @si28719e I have edited my answer to more clearly mentioned the "generated html" part. That allows you to revert your vote if you want.

Comment: The automatic page generator is no longer available (broken link), it's been replaced by the "theme chooser", see Github blog post: https://github.com/blog/2295-new-theme-chooser-for-github-pages

Comment: @dregad Thank you. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 10):

If you replace `index.html` with `index.md` containing your original markdown text, and add a ["Front Matter"](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/frontmatter/) section at the top, then you can do your page editing in markdown.

Answer (score 3):

It's totally possible and supported: just go back to "Settings", scroll down to GitHub Pages. The Source you used to create your initial page should still be there, and when you click on "Launch automatic page generator" it will allow you to update the markdown code right there in the browser.

When you're done you'll need to select the layout again, but once you're done with that it will create a new index.html, commit it using the GitHub pages source you chose, and publish the modified page.

Comment: I agree. +1 I have referenced your answer and added some examples in my own answer above.

Comment: This button is still under settings but the button now says "Change Theme". Still opens the editor, works great. Bad UX to hide a feature like that.

Answer (score 2):

You need Jekyll. The documentation you are looking for is here: https://help.github.com/articles/using-jekyll-with-pages