# Github pages: where's the markdown?

Tags: github, markdown, github-pages

When I created a github page I got to edit markdown.  Great.  Now I want to edit my page.  Problem is there's no markdown.  Just an `index.html` and a `params.json` that literally contain duplicated content.  I want to edit my site in the same markdown I got to edit it in when it was created.

This is very odd to me.  I don't understand why when I *create* a page I get to write markdown, but if I want to literally change one word in my initial commit I can't do it in that markdown file.  Presumably, I'm missing something obvious.

I think [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15044353/github-pages-how-do-i-edit-this-page-in-markdown-format-just-as-i-created-it) is trying to ask the same thing, but given that the accepted answer doesn't actually answer this question, I'm posting this as separate and will maybe figure out how to maintain that question later.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Hit the settings button

[image: settings]

Followed by the Automatic Page Generator button

[image: generator]

This will allow you to update the content of the site using GitHub’s system.

Comment: I see.  This is more meant to be a one-time shot generation that you hack up real quick than a page you maintain (like you know the whole idea behind something being version controlled) AFAICT.  Does that sound right?

Comment: @djechlin as I see it the "APG" is really just to help the newbies. Once you "get it" you should switch over to manual publish with Jekyll.

Comment: Hi there, I was wondering if I could safely delete the params.json if I'm not using the automatic page generator?

Answer (score 4):

If you replace `index.html` with `index.md` containing your original markdown text, and add a ["Front Matter"](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/frontmatter/) section at the top, then you can do your page editing in markdown instead of HTML.